# Trouble insert into booklist

Tags: c++

I am a little stuck on this area. By using `BookList.insert(book, Position::BOTTOM)` I would get cquery saying this error on the `BookList`:

> cannot use dot operator on a type

I can't think of another way to insert into `booklist` than this.

Could this be from the `if` statement? I intention it to do "if (stream works) {insert into booklist}".

Here is the code, and at the bottom there is a link to a picture of the code.

```cpp
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, BookList& book_list) {
  if (!book_list.containers_are_consistent()) {
    throw BookList::InvalidInternalStateException(
        "Container consistency error in operator>>");
  }
  std::string label_holder;
  size_t count;

    // Read in data from a stream and use it to fill in the data of a BookList
    // object. Create a function that will read the output created by the
    // ostream operator above into an object properly.

  stream >> count;
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      stream.ignore(100, ':');
    }
      if (stream) {
        BookList.insert(book, Position::BOTTOM);
    }
  return stream;
}
```

[image: Picture of code here]

Comment: Looks like BookList is a class. `BookList.insert(book, Position::BOTTOM);` does not make sense. You need an instance of the BookList to call insert. Perhaps you wanted `book_list.insert(book, Position::BOTTOM);`

Comment: @drescherjm Changing to `book_list.insert(book, Position::BOTTOM);` would underline `book` and `Position::Bottom` both saying use of undeclared identifier.

Comment: We can't really help with either of those because we don't have a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that `insert()` is a member function of the `BookList` class. If this assumption is correct, when using the `.` notation, it must be called on an *instance* of `BookList` rather than on the class name itself. So, replace this:

`BookList.insert(book, Position::BOTTOM);`

with this

`book_list.insert(book, Position::BOTTOM);`